# Django assets installed to different path than expected

Tags: python, django

I have my file structure in my django project like this

```
    ProjectA
        -ProjectA
        -user
        -static
            -js
            -images
            -css
        -manage.py
```

But after I did

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

The system is creating folders and files inside static folder outside i.e.

```
    ProjectA
        -css
        -js
        -images
        -ProjectA
        -user
        -static
        -manage.py
```

This is my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/django_projects/projectA/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/django_projects/mathMOOC/static')
```

My question is if I am doing it correctly or I need to make changes for    not generating those folders at that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with your directory structure, you need:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/django_projects/ProjectA/ProjectA/static'
```

To end up with the result you want.

Django [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#deployment) explain that you should set STATIC_ROOT to where you want to serve the files from, so this is where collectstatic collects them to. So this should explicitly be set to the directory you want to use.

Also it might be worth checking the capitalisation, you have projectA and ProjectA in use in your question, might be worth double checking which you should be using to keep things consistent and predictable.